# How do I upgrade PHP to 5.3 and MySQL along with it?

Tags: mysql, php, centos, rackspace

I’m running a Rackspace Cloud CentOS 5.5 instance.

It shipped with:

```
[root@server ~]# php -v
PHP 5.1.6 (cli) (built: Nov 29 2010 16:47:46) 
Copyright (c) 1997-2006 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.1.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2006 Zend Technologies
```

and

```
[root@server ~]# mysql --version
mysql  Ver 14.12 Distrib 5.0.77, for redhat-linux-gnu (x86_64) using readline 5.1
```

I want to upgrade it to at least PHP 5.2, and 5.3 if possible.

What are the proper steps for ensuring a smooth upgrade (with no data loss in MySQL, dependencies upgraded accordingly, etc.), and how would that upgrade actually be performed?

Answer (score 1):

Upgrading like that always has a risk of data loss. Therefore it's an extremely good idea to make backups of your files and database. After doing that, peruse [php upgrade](http://www.php.net/manual/en/migration52.php) and [mysql upgrade](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/upgrading-from-previous-series.html)

Edit:
It might be possible to go directly from 5.1 to 5.3, but to be safe you can go from 5.1->5.2, then from [5.2->5.3](http://www.php.net/manual/en/migration53.php).

Comment: php upgrade and mysql upgrade link to the same thing?

Comment: oops, sorry! updated php 5.1->5.2: http://www.php.net/manual/en/migration52.php. Updated the answer with correct link